# Pandas filter by comparing columns

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   Description     keyword
1  plays the piano   plays
2  plays the piano   write
3  plays the piano   piano
4 knows how to write  the
5 knows how to write  to
```

I want to filter it so that I keep the rows where the keyword is in the description. So here I would like to keep:

```
   Description     keyword
1  plays the piano   plays
3  plays the piano   piano
5 knows how to write  to
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is necessary match whole words only? So `then` matching with `the` ?

Comment: I think if need test by `df = df[[a in b.split() for a, b in zip(df.keyword, df.Description)]]` or by `df = df[[a in b for a, b in zip(df.keyword, df.Description)]]`

Comment: Yes I would like only whole words. So pian shouldn't work. know shouldn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x['keyword'] in x['Description'], axis=1)]
```

Comment: It is not exactly what I want since it does not solve the case discussed above but I see how this would work.